# How does unkeyed literals prevention work

Tags: go

Per this [doc](https://github.com/cristaloleg/go-advice#to-prevent-unkeyed-literals-add-_-struct-field)

> ```golang
> type Point struct {
>     X, Y float64
>     _    struct{} // to prevent unkeyed literals
> }
> ```
>
> For `Point{X: 1, Y: 1}` everything will be fine, but for `Point{1,1}` you will get a compile error:
>
> `./file.go:1:11: too few values in &Pointer literal`

Then I tried it in another data type `_ byte` and `_ func()` as below

```golang
type Pointer struct {
    X, Y int
    //_ byte   // to prevent unkeyed literals
    //_ func() // to prevent unkeyed literals
}
```

Both of them could prevent unkeyed literals. How does it prevent unkeyed literal? Is `_ struct{}` more efficient?

Comment: `struct{}` has a size of 0 bytes as per the specs IIRC, so it seems like the better choice.

Comment: @zangw have you seen this: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/NSjVW82i0mY

Comment: *"How does it prevent unkeyed literal?"* -- The type's irrelevant, it's the `_` that prevents the unkeyed literals because a field with the blank identifier cannot be assigned to (from outside the type's package) because it is unexported i.e. not upper case letter.

Comment: More efficient is just use a linter like `golangci` with `unkeyed fields` rule.

Answer (score 2):

Unkeyed structs *require* you to specify all struct keys; it is an error if you don't specify the value for `Y` for example:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y float64
}

_ = Point{1}

// Output:
// ./main.go:8:8: too few values in Point{...}
```

The `_  struct{}` field doesn't *really* prevent unkeyed literals from the same package, as you can still do:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y float64
    _    struct{} // to prevent unkeyed literals
}

_ = Point{1, 2, struct{}{}}
// Ugly and weird, but valid!
```

But in order to be able to assign values in struct fields from other packages they need to be "exported", that is, start with a capital letter, and `_` doesn't, so this is an error:

```
_ = x.Point{1, 2, struct{}{}}

// Output
// ./main.go:6:28: implicit assignment of unexported field '_' in x.Point literal
```

There is nothing special about `_`; you can use anything else that doesn't start with a capital as well, such as `noexport struct{}` or whatnot.

---

Why `struct{}` and not `byte` or `int`? Well, those types allocate some amount of memory; for an `int` it's usually 8 bytes (or 4 bytes on a 32bit system), and `byte` is an alias for `uint8` and allocates one byte.

`struct{}` on the other hand is an "empty" type (you can't assign anything to it) and won't use any memory. This is a very small optimisation, but if you're going to type something you might as well type `struct{}`.

---

Is all of this worth it? In my opinion it's not; if someone wants to use unkeyed struct literals with your library then that's their choice. Many lint tools will already warn on this, including the built-in `go vet`:

```
$ go vet main.go
./main.go:8:6: net/mail.Address composite literal uses unkeyed fields
```

Comment: "Unkeyed structs require you to specify all struct keys" - not exactly, there's no such thing as an "unkeyed struct". "Unkeyed" refers to the struct *literal* - a struct value expression, not the struct type itself. "There is nothing special about _" is also untrue; it is the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier).

Comment: It's accurate enough for the purpose of this answer @Adrian; and "unkeyed struct" vs "unkeyed struct literal" is just pedantic: everyone understands what's intended.

Comment: Regarding `_`, it's just false information. A field named `_` cannot be referenced. "Anything else that doesn't start with a capital" won't actually behave the same as `_` does.

Answer (score 2):

> How does it prevent unkeys literals works?

An unkeyed struct literal *must* specify *all* fields; by adding a field that cannot be specified from outside the package, it makes it impossible to use this format, so it requires a keyed literal. "Keyed" or "unkeyed" refers to whether the field names appear in the struct literal.

> Does _    struct{} more efficient?

Yes, because it has a width of zero, so it doesn't consume any memory. All other types would increase the memory footprint of the struct unnecessarily.